# Calling directive inside a function in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a directive called "drill-down" that I want to call inside a function as the one below but I dont know how to do this

```
$scope.drillDown = function() {

   some code...

   if(success == 200) {

      call the directive here    

   }
}
```

Now I use that directive in my view like this:

```
  <tr ng-repeat="d in data" class="child">
    <td ng-click="drillDown()" drill-down></td>
    <td>d.name</td>
    <td>d.lastname</td>
  </tr>
```

Some help will be great!

**DIRECTIVE CODE**

```
 angular.module('headline.Drilldown',[])
  .directive('drillDown',drillDown);


 function drillDown() {

var directive = {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: link
};

return directive;

function link(scope,element) {

    var table = $('.categories-table');

    table.each(function() {
        var $table = $(this);
        $table.find('.parent').each(function(){
            if($(this).nextUntil('.parent', ".child").length >= 0){
                $(this).children('td:first').html('+');
            }
        });
        $table.find('.child').each(function(){

            if($(this).nextUntil('.child', ".grandson").length >= 0){
               // $(this).children('td:first').html('+');
            }
        });

        var $childRows = $table.find('tbody tr').not('.parent').hide();
        $table.find('button.hide').click(function() {
            $childRows.hide();

        });
    });
    element.on('click',function(){
        if($(this).parent().hasClass('parent') === true)
        {
            console.log("----Parent");
            if ($(this).text() === "+")
                $(this).text("-")
            else
                $(this).text("+");

            $(this).parent().nextUntil('.parent', ".child").fadeToggle("fast", "linear");
            $(this).parent().nextUntil('.parent', ".grandson").hide("fast");
            $(this).parent().nextUntil('.parent', ".child").each(function(){

                if($(this).children('td:first').text() === '-')
                    $(this).children('td:first').text('+');
            });
        }
        else if($(this).parent().hasClass('child') === true)
        {
            console.log("----Child");
            if ($(this).text() === "+")
                $(this).text("-")
            else
                $(this).text("+");
            $(this).parent().nextUntil('.child',   ".grandson").fadeToggle("fast", "linear");
        }
    });
}

}
```

Comment: where is your directive code?

Comment: Hi and thanks for your time, 
I update my question with the directive code.

Comment: Not clear what the purpose of the directive is.  Can you explain what this directive does and why you aren't just using existing directives to achieve what you want?  Also like someone mentioned when this was first posted you would pass some variable into the directive that it would watch or observe and when that property's value changes you would do whatever work in the directive.

Comment: @shaunhusain

Hi, this directive help me to expand and collapse rows in an html table, Imagine I have five records, each record could have "child" records, its like doing drill-down on the "parent" records, so I made it using jquery cause is the way I knew, so someone told me to use a directive so I put my jquery code in the directive.

Comment: Gotcha, yeah doing DOM manipulation in directives is typically the way to go but if you just want collapsible rows you can just use an ng-click and ng-if or ng-show/ng-hide combination... let me try a sample and tell me what's wrong from there.

Comment: @shaunhusain

Thanks a lot, let me try your solution :)

Comment: @shaunhusain Thanks again, but one thing, in your example the hidden data apears next to the label, but I need something like this:

https://jsfiddle.net/h90Luy3h/

but this example is using a directive with jQuery,

Comment: @kennechu do you need it to work recursively or is it just categories and subcategories? I ask because there's a nice helper factory someone posted on SO here that can make it work recursively, so any object in the main array can have a subcategories property that has an array of objects all the way down?

Comment: @shaunhusain its just categories and subcategories.

Comment: @kennechu see the updates below I used ng-repeat-start and ng-repeat end and then another ng-repeat for the subcategories think this makes the most sense based on what I saw so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
angular.module('myApp',[])
  .controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $timeout){
     $scope.things = [
       {
         label:"thing 1",
         details: "here's some details",
         subcategories: [
           {label:"sub thing 1"},
           {label:"sub thing 2"},
           {label:"sub thing 3"}
         ]
       },
       {label:"thing 2", details: "here's some other details"},
       {label:"thing 3", details: "here's some details again"},
       {label:"thing 4", details: "alright we get the idea"},
     ]
       
       $scope.someAsyncThingHappens = function(){
         $timeout(function(){
           $scope.things[2].expanded = true;
         }, 500)
       }
  });
```

```css
.btn {
  cursor:pointer;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius:5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <table>
    <tr ng-repeat-start="thing in things" ng-click="thing.expanded = !thing.expanded">
      <td>
        <div class="btn" ng-if="!thing.expanded">+</div>
        <div class="btn" ng-if="thing.expanded">-</div>
      </td>
      <td>{{thing.label}} <span ng-if="thing.expanded">{{thing.details}}</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat-end ng-repeat="subthing in thing.subcategories" ng-if="thing.expanded">
      <td>x</td><td>{{subthing.label}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <button class="btn" ng-click="someAsyncThingHappens()">Simulate Async</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for you help, I really appreciate it!

Comment: No problem thanks for explaining the problem I can't read jQuery code :)